# Assigning free marker list to a Javascript Array

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, freemarker

Is it possible to assign a freemarker list to a Javascript Array? Does any other technique exist to achieve the same?

Suppose I have the following code

```
<#list messages.thread.messages.topic as message>
<div id="subject">${posts.subject}</div>
<div id="teaser">${posts.teaser}</div>
<div id="body">${message.body}</div>
</#list>

function script(){
   //I want to access the free marker list message here
}
```

Comment: You'll need to show what's the generated HTML. Also, are you using any library or just plain JavaScript?

Comment: What is a "free marker list"?

Comment: @jfriend00 - He's talking about FreeMarker - http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I don't find anything wrong in my question and yet it is voted negative. Check below for the answer I found out.

Comment: +1 to offset pointless downvote.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes it is possible

```
var arr=[<#list messages.thread.messages.topic as message>${message.body},</#list>]
```

Comment: Thanks! For me, the following worked as it was a long data type. `var arr = [<#list dataIds as dId>${dId?c},</#list>];`

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.  You need to arrange that your Freemarker template generates a Javascript array literal and assigns it to the appropriate Javascript variable.  Start with the syntax of a Javascript array literal and then figure out how to generate one using Freemarker constructs.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I found how to.

Comment: I don't find anything wrong in my question and yet it is voted negative.

Comment: @rozar - yea.  Stuff like that happens.  People assume that since they don't understand the question that it must be a poor question.  Don't worry about it.